# How to invoke other programs in Racket?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, pandoc

I can successfully run pandoc in Windows CMD using the command:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.html
```

Then I want do the same in Racket, I tried:

```
(subprocess #f #f #f "pandoc" "test.md -o test.html")
```

and:

```
(shell-execute "pandoc" "" "test.md -o test.html" (current-directory) 'sw_showdefault)
```

But none of them gave me the expected `.html` file.

What is the correct way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "didn't work".  Did you get an error? If so, what was it?  Did you get no error, but something else happened?  Note that the _successful_ return value for `shell-execute` is `#f`, which might be misleading.  (E.g., "It returned false!  Why didn't it work? Oh, returning false means that it _did_ work!")

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks. I should have described the exact behavior. They didn't give me any error message, but they didn't give the expected `.html` file either. I tried Greg's answer with `(system "pandoc test.md -o test.html")`. It works fine this time.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Joshua that it's hard to know how to answer your question as you originally asked it. Maybe you'll edit it. Meanwhile, to answer it as originally asked:

I think the equivalent of "typing it at the command prompt" in Racket would be [`system`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/system..rkt%29._system%29%29), or better [`system*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/system..rkt%29._system%2a%29%29).

```
(system "pandoc test.md -o test.html")
```

Comment: By the way, if your goal is solely to do `.md` -> `.html` conversion in Racket, there's a [Markdown parser written in Racket](https://github.com/greghendershott/markdown). Disclosure: I wrote it. Disclaimer: It is not my best Racket code and I suck at parsers. I can't promise the quality is >= that of pandoc. But I am using it for real in a blogging tool.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, and since comments can be deleted, could you update your answer with the code the @Ben said worked for him, i.e., `(system "pandoc test.md -o test.html")`?  I think this would make the answer stand on its own a little bit more.

Comment: Thank you, Greg. `system` works fine. I chose pandoc because it has a better spec than the original one by John Gruber. Your package seems a great option, too. I will try it.

Comment: And I have looked at Frog before, I remember that it was written in a lang called `rackjure` which I was not familiar with. So I didn't choose it. But I can't find any information about the lang in From readme now. Did I misremember it?

Comment: @Ben No worries if you're not comfortable with it and don't want to use it. [`#lang rackjure`](https://github.com/greghendershott/rackjure) is essentially normal Racket plus a few extra bits. The bit I use the most in Frog is the `~>` threading macro, to write nested function calls in a flat, data flow style. It's not essential, I just find it clearer in some cases.